# Mypy type of concatenate tuples

Tags: python, mypy

I have a function that takes specific tuples and concatenates and I am trying to specify the type of the output but mypy does not agree with me.

File `test.py`:

```
from typing import Tuple

def test(a: Tuple[str, str], b: Tuple[int, int]) -> Tuple[str, str, int, int]:
    return a + b
```

running mypy 0.641 as `mypy --ignore-missing-imports test.py` I get:

```
test.py:5: error: Incompatible return value type (got "Tuple[Any, ...]", expected "Tuple[str, str, int, int]")
```

Which i guess is true but more generic, given that I specify my inputs.

Comment: This appears to have been fixed. using mypy 1.0.1, I get "Success: no issues found in 1 source file". Probably with https://github.com/python/mypy/pull/7409

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This <strike>is</strike> was a [known issue](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/224), but <strike>there appears to be no timeline for enabling `mypy`</strike>was fixed later in 2019 to do the correct type inference.

Comment: This seems to have been fixed on September 2019 https://github.com/python/mypy/pull/7409

Comment: Indeed! The linked issue was closed on September 2, 2019 as well.

Answer (score 1):

Concatenation of fixed-length tuples is not currently supported by `mypy`. As a workaround, you can construct a tuple from individual elements:

```
from typing import Tuple

def test(a: Tuple[str, str], b: Tuple[int, int]) -> Tuple[str, str, int, int]:
    return a[0], a[1], b[0], b[1]
```

or using [unpacking](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/) if you have Python 3.5+:

```
def test(a: Tuple[str, str], b: Tuple[int, int]) -> Tuple[str, str, int, int]:
    return (*a, *b)  # the parentheses are required here
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a less-verbose workaround (python3.5+):

```
from typing import Tuple

def f(a: Tuple[str, str], b: Tuple[int, int]) -> Tuple[str, str, int, int]:
    return (*a, *b)
```